# How Do I Show Notification Through Notification Channels?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a app that is using a foreground service with a notification. The service is working fine, and it's not being killed by the system when I check running services under developer options on the device. However, when I start the service, it's not showing the notification in my notification drawer. I am new to Kotlin, and I took an old Java notification code that I had, and I tried to convert the codes to Kotlin, but it's not working. According to my researches, this should be working. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my project codes...

Notification Class:

```
class NotificationService : Service() {

    private val CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ONE"

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createNotificationChannel()
    }

    @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channelName = "Photo Text Copier"
            val channelDescription = "Takes Snapshots and Copies the Text from Images!"
            val importance: Int = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, importance).apply {
                description = channelDescription
            }
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            sendNotification()
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotification(): Int {
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Photo Text Copier")
            .setContentText("Takes Snapshots and Copies the Text from Images!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build()

        startForeground(1, builder)
        return START_STICKY
    }

}
```

build.gradle Project:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

build.gradle Module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.mycompany.NotificationService'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.NotificationService"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url='https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url='https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}
rootProject.name = "NotificationService"
include ':app'
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NotificationService"
        tools:targetApi="33">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".NotificationService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Calling the Notification Class from MainActivity Class:

```
serviceIntent = Intent(this, NotificationService::class.java)
                        startService(serviceIntent)
```

I appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: Kotlin's just another way to write the same code as with Java, it doesn't do anything different - if it worked in Java it should work in Kotlin! Starting in Android 12 (API 31+) foreground notifications don't display for the first 10 seconds (see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) so short-lived foreground services can run and complete without popping up a notification - I don't know if that applies to what you're doing. Also make sure your service definitely is running in the foreground independently, by swiping your Activity away

Comment: Yeah, my service is working great. I swiped out of the app and the service and process kept running. It's been nearly 5 minutes and it hasn't been killed by the system yet. Also, even after 10 seconds there is no notification. It's not popping up at all no matter how long I wait. I really want this notification to display. I want my users to end the service by clicking the action button through pending intent and broadcast receiver.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem! I didn't have post notifications in my manifest as a uses permission, and I had to use a permission prompt to allow this permission. After that, problem resolved. I didn't know android made that change. It's been since API 28 or 29 since I worked with notifications. I don't remember needing permissions before. Some things I am behind on unfortunately. But hey, at least I am catching on with the updates.

Comment: You shouldn't need it to just start a foreground service, since that's a special kind of notification - see here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission But yeah you need it for general notifications! And it's possible for the user to revoke that permission too - it's worth reading that section since it's all kinda in flux at the moment, and the way the transition is handled depends on a few things.

Comment: Evidently, I am not getting my intention for this across plain enough. I know that I don't need a notification to start a foreground service. The reason for the notification is because I wanted it, not because I thought I needed it. If the user decides to revoke that permission then that's their choice. My desire to do it this way is to give my users a shortcut to stop the foreground service by clicking the action button on the notification. Whether or not my users use that shortcut, that is their choice.

Comment: No I'm saying you don't need the *permission* to display the notification that's *required* for a foreground service (see the note in blue at the top of that linked page). You need it for *other* notifications you want to display. I don't know why adding it fixed the specific issue you were seeing, but I'm just pointing out how the spec defines the behaviour and requirements in case you run into other problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question. Here is the solution that worked for me just in case anyone in the future has this same problem.

In your `Manifest` add this:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>`

Then you want to prompt the user in your `MainActivity` with a permission request like this:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val PERMISSION_NOTIFICATION: Int = 100

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.notificationServiceButton.setOnClickListener {
           notificationServicePermission()
        }
   }

  private fun notificationServicePermission() {
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == 
             PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
             val notificationPermission = (Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
             requestPermissions(arrayOf(notificationPermission), 
             PERMISSION_NOTIFICATION)
        }else{
             startNotificationService()
            }
     }else {
        startNotificationService()
      }
  }

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_NOTIFICATION -> {
                if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startNotificationService()
                }else{
                    Snackbar.make(binding.container, HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<b>Permission Denied!</b>",
                        HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }


private fun startNotificationService() {
        serviceIntent = Intent(this, NotificationService::class.java)
        startService(serviceIntent)
    }
```